# RODBC ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect in mysql

Tags: mysql, r, impala

I have been trying to write an R script to query Impala database. Here is the query to the database:

```
select columnA, max(columnB) from databaseA.tableA where columnC in (select distinct(columnC) from databaseB.tableB ) group by columnA order by columnA
```

When I run this query manually (read: outside the Rscript via impala-shell), I am able to get the table contents. However, when the same is tried via the R script, I get the following error:

```
[1] "HY000 140 [Cloudera][ImpalaODBC] (140) Unsupported query."       
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'select columnA, max(columnB) from databaseA.tableA where columnC in (select distinct(columnC) from databaseB.tableB ) group by columnA order by columnA'
closing unused RODBC handle 1
```

Why does the query fail when tried via R? and how do I fix this? Thanks in advance :)

**Edit 1:**

The connection script looks as below:

```
library("RODBC");
connection <- odbcConnect("Impala");
query <- "select columnA, max(columnB) from databaseA.tableA where columnC in (select distinct(columnC) from databaseB.tableB ) group by columnA order by columnA";
data <- sqlQuery(connection,query);
```

Comment: How does your connection script look

Comment: I have updated my question with the connection script.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. My ODBC connection works fine with a simple query, so it's not an ODBC issue. Did you find any solution @GowthamGanesh?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I think it doesnt support complex queries like "group by"

Comment: From what I've found through various forums, RODBC does not seem to offer support for complex queries. I ended up switching to python and impyla. Ibis for impala also looks promising....

Comment: I was having the same problem.   I just updated the drivers as R4nc1d suggested, and now I can do complex queries with "group by" and multiple joins and unions

Comment: I also have the same issue from R to run a stored procedure in SQL. However, I observed that it does complete the stored procedure but it also throws error. I think it has something to do with time, if it crosses certain time, it throws this error..

Comment: I had a similar issue except my SQL statement was an `EXEC`.  It turned out that the problem was nested INSERT-EXEC, almost as though RODBC had been inserting an extra layer of INSERTs, so my stored procedure worked fine outside R but fell apart in R.  Did you ever end up solving your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the relevant drivers, please look at the following [link](http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/make-r-talk-to-mysql-on-windows/)

I had the same issue, all i had to do was update the ODBC drivers.

Also if you can update your odbcConnect with the username and password

```
connection <- odbcConnect("Impala");
```

to

```
connection <- odbcConnect("Impala", uid="root", pwd="password")
```

Comment: I did try installing the relevant drivers. However, nothing looks promising. I did try simple queries and they seem to go through fine and the issue comes when I try using complex queries involving joins and the like.

Comment: Did you check your ODBC configuration in your OS?

Answer (score 1):

The RODBC package is quirky: if there's no row updated/deleted in the query execution it will throw an error.

So before using `sqlDelete` to delete rows, or using `sqlUpdate` to update values, first check if there's at least one row that will be deleted/updated by querying `COUNT(*)`.

I've had no problem after implementing the check, for Oracle SQL 12g.

---

**An alternative** would be to use a staging table for the new batch of data, and use `sqlQuery` to execute a `MERGE` command. RODBC won't complaint if there's zero row merged.

Comment: can't believe this didn't get more upvotes. thanks man. could have been here all night without figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

This might also be due to an error in your sql query itself. For example, I got this error when I missed an 'in' in the following generalized statement. Example:

```
stringstuff <- someDT$columnyouwanttouse

somestring <- toString(sprintf("'%s'", stringstuff)) 

RESULTS <- sqlQuery(con,  paste0("select

                        fling as flam

                        and toot **in** (",somestring,")

                        limit 30
                        ;"))
```

I got the error you did when I left out the **'in'**, so double check your syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This error message can arise if the table doesn't exist in the database.

A few sensible checks:

- Check for typos in the table name in your query
- See if you can run the same query on the same database via another sql client
- Talk to your data base administrator to confirm that the table does exist

Answer (score 0):

Re-installing the RODBC package did the trick for me!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. After unnisntalling the R version 4.2.1 and install the R version 4.1.3 the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm, using version 4.1.3 RODBC works properly but with latest version (4.3.2) doesn't work (AS400 database).

Strange thing I noted is that on version 4.3.1 connecting via ODBC a MySQL database it works properly.

resuming what I found is:

R version 4.1.3 and RODBC Version 1.3-20 works properly on AS400 database

R version 4.3.1 and RODBC Version 1.3-20 works properly on MySQL database

R version 4.3.1 and .2 and RODBC Version 1.3-23 doesn't work on AS400 database

I hope it will help who has this problem

CZ

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35632317)